# az vm run-command doesn't work in github actions

Tags: github, azure-pipelines, github-actions, azure-cli

I am trying to get the exit code as 0 or 1 from az vm run-command.

> `az vm run-command invoke -g myRG -n myVM --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "/home/azureuser/cassandra-script.sh" -o json | grep nodetool`

but either my script succeeds or fails it gives the "$?" as 0.
so decided to put " | grep xxxxx " but with this, it gives an error

> `Error: Error: az cli script failed.
> cleaning up container...
> MICROSOFT_AZURE_CLI_1654967445460_CONTAINER

> (node:1679) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)`

however, when I try to run the same command from azure cloud cli it works fine. but I want to use it in the GitHub actions pipeline Please help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Action Run Command**, we have certain [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command#restrictions).

The run-command **requires port 443 connectivity**. If the extension lacks access to these endpoints, the **scripts** may **run successfully but fail to return results**.

If you are using a **[Managed Run Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command-managed)** this allows us to run multiple scripts in parallel. But it is still in preview mode.

The **`az vm run-command`** invoke is working in Azure CLI but still have some bugs to run in pipelines. Refer the **`Az vm run-command invoke`** Github [issue 1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/21111) & [issue 2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20495#issuecomment-1042565846)